# How do I use WHERE EXISTS function in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, phpmyadmin

For the last 6-7 hours I've been searching/googling/experimenting for a solution to this but no results so far.

I have an SQL string(below) which works PERFECTLY in PHPMYADMIN but doesn't work within my java execution. When attempting to execute the query I get "*Column **rid** Not Found.*"

SQLException:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'rid' not found.
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1167)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2851)
at net.matthewauld.racetrack.server.WrSQL.getJSONClassSpecificRiders(WrSQL.java:41)
at net.matthewauld.racetrack.server.ClientListener.parseCommand(ClientListener.java:110)
at net.matthewauld.racetrack.server.ClientListener.run(ClientListener.java:42)
```

--

```
SELECT * FROM `riders` WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `ridersclasses` WHERE ridersclasses.rid = riders.id AND `cid` = '6') ORDER BY `first_name` ASC
```

Here is my java code to execute the SQL Query.

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/racetrack2013?allowMultiQueries=true";
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
st = con.createStatement();
rs = st.executeQuery(query);
```

Below I will post the structure of the two tables and some data examples:

**RidersClasses**

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                   ridersclasses                   |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|  ID  |  RID  |  CID  |  BIKENUMBER  |  BIKEMODEL  |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

**Riders**

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                         Riders                                   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  ID  |  first_name  | last_name  |  address  |  city_id  |  h_phone  |  c_phone  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Those are tilde keys, part of SQL...

Comment: IMO, it would be more helpful if you could post the (whole) stacktrace.

Comment: Did you try naming your tables using the AS keyword? Eg: ....from ridersclasses as rideClass .... Then referennce them like rideClass.rid = ...

Comment: @MatthewAuld I think you have to try with the exact name of table name and column name as case sensitive.

Comment: @ns47731 I've attempted adding the AS keywords for each table but I still get the same error.

Comment: @MatthewAuld maybe the problem is in jdbc .. have you tried `rs.getInt("RID")` ? where rs is the result set

Comment: @YogeshSuthar if you look at the information I've provided you will see that it is already properly cased.

Comment: Does rewriting the query help?  Did you try `SELECT * FROM riders WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM ridersclasses WHERE CID = '6') ORDER BY first_name ASC`

Comment: I think the error happens after the execution when you trying to read a column from the row, by looking at your exception.

Comment: @Stephan I can't get the ResultSet if the query isn't executing correctly.

Comment: @devnull That query doesn't work either.

Comment: @DAevZer0 I think you pegged that. Thrown from getInt()

Comment: @DevZer0 your theory worked! **Thank you so much!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is simple : there's no `rid` column in `riders` table.

As its shown in the strack trace the problem starts at `getInt`

So instead of `rs.getInt("rid")` use `rs.getInt("id")`

Comment: Good call you might add that to get the rid you could use a left join instead of the EXISTS

Comment: @ns47731 Thanks, i thought of that but rid = id so its not necessary